# How to make a QML file object which is located in child directory?

Tags: qt, qml

If i am making a large qt project, in which i am using many qml files with file organize. I mean the main.qml file located in qrc:/ and other files are located in child directory link qrc:/examplePage/exmp1.qml, Then how can i make a object in main.qml file of this qrc:/examplePage/exmp1.qml file.

Right now the situation is all the 50 files are located in qrc:/ directory and i want to organize them and make folders with respect to category.

Thank you very much.

I am makeing object in main.qml file like:

exmp1{
id:exmp
visible: false
}

and show this on button.onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import the directory (and I would suggest that you uppercase the first letter of each QML file, as that is the convention):

```
import "examplePage"

Exmp1 {
    id: exmp
    visible: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Loader and setting your QML file as the source. Loader will always load the item and attempt to fill the parent . If you want a defined Size of your QML within the main QML you can place it in a rectangle like this .

```
Rectangle
{
         width:200
         height:200
Loader {
         id: testing
         source: "qrc:/examplePage/exmp1.qml"
       }
}
```